# React + Typescript: Property * is missing in type *

Tags: javascript, typescript, reactjs

I'm trying to go through the [React Tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html), but there is an error occurring that I don't understand.

The error messages are:

```
comment.tsx(30,5): error TS2324: Property 'data' is missing in type 'MyProps'.
comment.tsx(31,5): error TS2324: Property 'data' is missing in type 'MyProps'.
main.tsx(20,17): error TS2324: Property 'author' is missing in type 'MyProps'.
main.tsx(27,18): error TS2324: Property 'author' is missing in type 'MyProps'.
```

Here is `main.tsx`:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import 'jquery';
import { CommentList, CommentForm, MyProps } from './comment';

var data = [
  {author: "Pete Hunt", text: "This is one comment"},
  {author: "Jordan Walke", text: "This is *another* comment"}
];

class CommentBox extends React.Component<MyProps, {}> {
    render() {
        return <div className="commentBox">
                <h1>Comments</h1>
                <CommentList data={this.props.data} />
                <CommentForm />
                </div>;
    }
}

$(() => {
    React.render(<CommentBox data={data} />, document.getElementById('content'));
});
```

And `comment.tsx`:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export interface MyProps extends React.Props<any> {
    author: string;
    data: Array<any>;
}

export class Comment extends React.Component<MyProps, {}> {
    render() {
        let rawMarkup = marked(this.props.children.toString(), {sanitize: true});
        return <div className="comment">
                 <h2 className="commentAuthor">
                   {this.props.author}
                 </h2>
                 <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: rawMarkup}} />
               </div>;
    }
}

export class CommentList extends React.Component<MyProps, {}> {
    render() {
        return <div className="commentList">
                <Comment author="Pete Hunt">Some comment</Comment>
                <Comment author="Jordan Walke">Another *comment*</Comment>
                </div>;
    }
}

export class CommentForm extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    render() {
        return <div className="commentForm">
               A CommentForm
               </div>;
    }
}
```

I remember reading that interfaces are only for type checking and do not exist in the transpiled code. However, I still don't fully understand why I'm getting these errors.

Also, I'm using the type definitions from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/react.d.ts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> comment.tsx(30,5): error TS2324: Property 'data' is missing in type 'MyProps'.
>   comment.tsx(31,5): error TS2324: Property 'data' is missing in type 'MyProps'.
>   main.tsx(20,17): error TS2324: Property 'author' is missing in type 'MyProps'.
>   main.tsx(27,18): error TS2324: Property 'author' is missing in type 'MyProps'.

You are probably confusing `MyProps` for `CommentList` (does not contain `.author`) and `MyProps` for `Comment` (does not contain `.data`).

Better if you use *different* Prop interfaces for the two components.

Comment: Thanks. Creating separate interfaces solved the problem. Looking at the transpiled JS helped also, basically `<Comment author="Pete Hunt">Some comment</Comment>` becomes `React.createElement(Comment, {"author": "Pete Hunt"}, "Some comment")`. So a `prop` in JavaScript is just `{"author": "Pete Hunt"}`.
So TypeScript was telling me I never used the `data` property on `Comment`?  I'm still a little fuzzy on how interfaces work in TypeScript. Basically why are there two `MyProps`?

Comment: Two separate interfaces for two separate *contracts* for two separate components

Comment: Thanks. I guess `contract` is the key word. The first parameter (P)  to `React.Component<P, S>` defines the shape of properties, so I need to make sure the properties I use matches with that.